# Derangement with a limit of minimum distance

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

Formally,

Count the number of permutations $p = \operatorname{permute}[1, 2, \ldots, n]$ , such that $\forall 1 \le i \le n, |p(i) - i| \ge K$, where $K$ is a given constant.

For example, when $K=1$, the problem is reduced to the normal derangement problem.

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: [OEIS A306543](https://oeis.org/A306543) does not suggest a formula, though [OEIS A001883](https://oeis.org/A001883) does for $K=2$